# Web server behind NAT fails reCaptcha validation

Tags: webserver, recaptcha, nat

IIS Web server is behind a linux NAT, all web services function successfully except one form that requires reCaptcha validation. The same form works without the NAT and when tested locally. So it's not the configuration from Google reCaptcha settings.

ports 80 and 443 are being routed with iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -d [nat-IP] -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to [web-IP]
```

security groups (on AWS):
Web-security: allow all inbound from NAT, all outbound open
Nat-security: allow all 80 and 443, all outbound open

Apparently google is not able to validate behind the NAT, how can I configure?

Answer (score 0):

The solution involved making the ajax call for reCaptcha asynchronous.
async: true
It was set to false previously.

UPDATE:  Actually reCaptcha is very slow if the route table in AWS is not setup properly.

VPC > Route Tables (left pane) > your-private-Route-Table

Edit Route:

destination: 0.0.0.0/0

target :
select "instance" then choose your NAT instance

Comment: Forgot to also include that actually you'll need to add to your private route table destination: 0.0.0.0/0   target :   i-<nat-instance>